# An endomorphism sending a basis element to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $\mathbb R_n[X]$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$. Let $u$ be the endomorphism 
$$u(P)=(X^2-1)P''-2XP'$$

I want to determine the determinant of $u$. So I proceed by computing the images of the basis $(1,X,\cdots ,X^n)$. But since $u(1)=0$ it is clear that matrix of $u$ will have a zero column so the determinant is zero. Is this correct? Is it always true that any endomorphism having one element of the basis in its kernel has determinant zero?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Isn't true that any element can be made part of a basis, since any non zero element is linearly independent so by the exchange lemma it can be completed by other elements from a generating system. What if this element is in the kernel of the endomorphism, then we will always have determinant zero !!!!

Comment: Indeed, that is why the answer is yes.

Comment: This means that any endomorphism $u$ with $\ker u\not =\{0\}$, that is any non injective endomorphism has determinant zero, is this true??

Comment: oh ok i see any non bijective endomorphism has determinant zero wich means that any non injective or non surjective endomorphism has determinant zero.